# Hiding/Locking commit history in Git

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab

I am looking for a solution to block certain users from being able to view the commit history for a repository.

Other than deleting the older commits, is there a way to keep the commits but hide them or lock them?

Comment: Give them the latest revision and work with patches

Comment: Yeah, in this case share the source folder without sharing the repo.

Comment: Any links or articles you'd recommend on how this is done?

Comment: There has no such settings for Github repo.

Answer (score -1):

You can block the user as explained in the page https://help.github.com/articles/blocking-a-user-from-your-personal-account/

Comment: I'm not looking to block users, just want them only to be able to see the latest revision of my files.